# Is it true that an org.bukkit.entity.Player object holds chunks loaded even if the player is disconnected?

Tags: bukkit

I heard somewhere that org.bukkit.entity.Player objects hold chunks loaded even if the player is disconnected, so they should not be used for data storage. My question is: Is this true, and if it is, what should I do instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I heard somewhere that org.bukkit.entity.Player objects hold chunks loaded even if the player is disconnected ... My question is: Is this true

No. Whenever a player quits or is accidentally disconnected, the player is removed from `PlayerChunkMap` thereby allowing associated chunks to be removed provided they are not within range of other players or plugins purposely keeping chunks loaded. Chunks remain in memory until the server can save them.

> ...so they should not be used for data storage... and if it is, what should I do instead?

To persist data between player sessions or server restarts, a player's data - whatever that may be - should be keyed to their `UUID`, which can be retrieved via `getUniqueId()`.

For example, an event listener for `PlayerQuitEvent` retrieves player data and their UUID, saving data to a YAML file or database table(s). A corresponding `PlayerJoinEvent` event handler gets the player's UUID, reads or queries associated data and applies as needed. Prior to Mojang switching to UUIDs, the same was achieved using a player's name, which at that time was unique and could not be changed.

A `Player` object is only unique for the duration of a player's session. While it could be used as a key to maps, lookup tables, or other data structures, you should always use the player's UUID instead. Furthermore, it should be mentioned that a player's UUID returned by `getUniqueId()` is not the same as the player's Entity Id returned by `getEntityId()`. Players will have different entity ids every time they join.

Answer (score 2):

Just store the Player's UUID:

`player.getUniqueId()`

and then get the player with:

`Bukkit.getPlayer(uuid)`

Comment: So I assume that you imply that it's not good to store Player objects. Ok, thanks!

Comment: You should always store the UUID and never the Player object itself. If this answered your question please click on the check mark to the left of the answer to accept it.